# Metasploit console not opening

Tags: console, debian, metasploit

Whenever I try to run Metasploit on my Debian 9 cloud instance, the console will be "killed"

> user@debian:~$ msfconsole
>
> NOTE: Inheriting Faraday::Error::ClientError is deprecated; use Faraday::ClientError instead. It will be removed in or after version 1.0
>   Faraday::Error::ClientError.inherited called from /opt/metasploit-framework/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/octokit-4.14.0/lib/octokit/middleware/follow_redirects.rb:14.
>
> [*] Starting the Metasploit Framework Console...-
>
> **Killed**

The database and webserver were running successfully before launching the msfconsole command.

> Starting database at /home/user/.msf4/db...**success**
>
> MSF web service is no longer running
>   Deleting MSF web
>
> Attempting to start MSF web service...**success**
>   MSF web service started and online

The nightly Metasploit releases were used to initially install Metasploit.

Answer (score 0):

You can try by uninstalling `msfconsole` with this command `apt --purge remove msfconsole` and reinstall using `apt install msfconsole`

Comment: msfconsole is not a package. If reinstalling is something someone would like to try, the correct package name is metasploit-framework.